# How to run an c# exe child process from node and recieves messages back and forth?

Tags: c#, node.js, exe, child-process

In node.js, I want to create a child process that runs an exe (created by my c# code). I want to pass some data from node.js to the exe, and then get back data from the exe.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be a child process? Does it have to be an executable? If the answer is no to both questions, you could use [Edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge).

Comment: Maybe checkout... http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/ ... and https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ItsJustASoftwareIssueEdgejsBringsNodeAndNETTogetherOnThreePlatforms.aspx

Comment: I could possibly use this, but how do I send data back from c# to node.js? Also I use these three imports in c# `using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;` how would I load them in node.js?

Comment: I could perhaps help you, but you could also try [RTFM](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge#how-to-specify-additional-clr-assembly-references-in-c-code)

Answer (score 1):

Data can be passed to child process by environment variable or stdin, and child process can send data by writing to stdout. like this:

```
const testData = JSON.stringify({ a: 1, b: 2 });
const result = require('child_process').execSync('printenv TEST_DATA',{
    env: { TEST_DATA: testData }
});
console.log(JSON.parse(result));
```

or

```
const result = require('child_process').execSync('cat',{
    input: testData
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you can call the process, as for passing parameters, I would simply pass arguments and have it read the data from the disk. So just pass it the location of the files and have your C# program read those files. Don't need to pass the word files themselves.

Comment: The arguments will be strings though

Comment: ? Not sure why that is an issue. If you want to give your C# program a word file you can give it a string of the url and it can then load it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Just wanted to know if i could pass strings or not

Comment: Yes you can pass them as arguments (args) in the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html